# Why permission denied occured when accessing my local website?

Tags: docker, nginx, fpm

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 and docker.
Currently I have 2 docker containers from bitnami, 1 is for nginx, the other one is php-fpm.
Here's my docker-compose config for nginx :

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: 'bitnami/nginx:latest'
    group_add:
      - www-data
    restart: always
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - 'nginx_data:/bitnami'
      - ~/Documents/nginx/nginx.conf:/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ~/Documents/nginx/my_vhost.conf:/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/my_vhost.conf:ro
      - /usr/share/nginx/html:/app

volumes:
  nginx_data:
    driver: local
```

and here's my docker-compose.yml for php-fpm :

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: 'bitnami/php-fpm:latest'
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/nginx/html:/app
      - ~/Documents/nginx/nginx.conf:/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ~/Documents/nginx/my_vhost.conf:/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/my_vhost.conf
```

Also, here's my nginx config :

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
  server_name localhost;
  root /app;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location /evodms {                                                                                                                                                  
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then                                                                                                                  
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.                                                                                                             
    # root /usr/share/nginx/html;                                                                                                                                     
    # root /var/www/html/evodms;                                                                                                                                    
    try_files $uri $uri/ /evodms/index.php?$args;                                                                                                                   
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                 
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;                                                                                                       
    fastcgi_index  index.php;                                                                                                                               
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                    
    include        fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                          
  }
}
```

I have started all the containers and the nginx container generated user 1001, so I mapped this user to www-data, FYI, my evodms folder ownership has been set to www-data.
But I received this message :

```
nginx_1  | 2017/10/14 06:12:39 [error] 25#0: *1 directory index of "/app/evodms/" is forbidden, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /evodms/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2017:06:12:39 +0000] "GET /evodms/ HTTP/1.1" 403 198 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Any clue?

Comment: Why do you have two compose files?

Comment: I'm using 2 separated docker images

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx try to find index.html in evodms folder. because of you set your index as `index index.htm index.html` under root option.

I guess that your evodms is exists under your public folder right?

if you set location path like this.

```
location /evodms {                                                                                                                                                  
   try_files $uri $uri/ /evodms/index.php?$args;                                                                                                                   
}
```

look at try_files. the order is $uri then $uri/.
nginx will check if url /evodms/ is a folder? if yes, return it. but if it isn't, nginx will try other option.

How to check. 
first, try add file index.html in your evodms folder. It will show in your page if your access it, because nginx successfull define evodms as folder.

or just take out `$uri/` from `try_files`. so nginx wan't try to define evodms as folder. It will directly rewrite as next options. which is `evodms/index.php?$args`.

Answer (score 0):

The location of `/evodms` from your nginx configuration works for all requests starts from `/evodms`, so, for example, when you request `/evodms/test`, nginx tries `/app/evodms/test` file first, then `/app/evodms/test/` folder and finally tries `/app/evodms/index.php?$args`.

But when you request `/evodms/`, it tries `/app/evodms/`, which is `/` for location `/evodms`. In this case nginx tries index files, which you defined in `index` option. It seems you don't have `index.html` and `index.htm` in your `/app/evodms` folder, so you gets 403 forbidden error.

In order to fix request to `<your_domain>/evodms/`, you should add `index.php` to list of index files:

```
index index.htm index.html index.php;
```